# install numpy 1.19 with MKL on ubuntu using anaconda?

Tags: numpy, pip, anaconda, intel-mkl

When I do `pip search numpy`  I got the following:

```
numpy (1.19.2)                            - NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
  INSTALLED: 1.19.1
  LATEST:    1.19.2
   ....
intel-numpy (1.15.1)                      - NumPy optimized with Intel(R) MKL library
  ....
```

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 with pip 20.2.3 and anaconda 4.6.8. Is that the numpy w/ MKL version in pip is only up to that 1.15.1 version, and we have to build from source if we want 1.19.x version?

I tried using `conda install numpy` and it gave me openBLAS version for 1.19.2 and BLAS for 1.19.1